# finding the minimum value in a 2d chart without using math

Tags: javascript

i am wondering is there a shorter way to solve this problem

the numbers given below. i need to find minimum option in minimum natural situation without using math.min and i need to use for and function commands.

|  | N1 | N2 | N3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| option 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| option 2 | 40 | 50 | 60 |
| option 3 | 70 | 80 | 90 |
| option 4 | 100 | 110 | 120 |

I did this but i am wondering is there a another or shorter way to solve the problem?

```
const strategyTable = [
  [10, 20, 30],
  [40, 50, 60],
  [70, 80, 90],
  [100, 110, 120]
];
function findLowestDecisionAndLowestValue(strategyTable) {
  let lowestDecision = 1;
  let lowestValue = strategyTable[0][0];
  for (let i = 0; i < strategyTable[0].length; i++) {
    let columnMinimum = strategyTable[0][i]; //
    for (let j = 0; j < strategyTable.length; j++) {
      if (strategyTable[j][i] < columnMinimum) {
        columnMinimum = strategyTable[j][i];
      }
    }
    if (columnMinimum < lowestValue) {
      lowestValue = columnMinimum;
      lowestDecision = i + 1;
    }
  }

  return { lowestDecision, lowestValue };
}
let { lowestDecision, lowestValue } = findLowestDecisionAndLowestValue(strategyTable);
console.log("Lowest value: " + lowestValue);
console.log("Lowest decision Option " + lowestDecision);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your code is already quite efficient and readable. However, if you want to make it a bit shorter, you can combine the two for loops into one by using the reduce method. Here’s how you can do it:

```
const strategyTable = [
  [12500, 5000, 10000],
  [7850, 4900, 9730],
  [6250, 11600, 8450],
  [12300, 9880, 15230]
];

function findLowestDecisionAndLowestValue(strategyTable) {
  let lowestDecision = 0;
  let lowestValue = Infinity;

  for (let i = 0; i < strategyTable[0].length; i++) {
    let columnMinimum = strategyTable.reduce((min, row) => row[i] < min ? row[i] : min, Infinity);
    if (columnMinimum < lowestValue) {
      lowestValue = columnMinimum;
      lowestDecision = i + 1;
    }
  }

  return { lowestDecision, lowestValue };
}

let { lowestDecision, lowestValue } = findLowestDecisionAndLowestValue(strategyTable);
console.log("Lowest value: " + lowestValue);
console.log("Lowest decision Option " + lowestDecision);
```

This version of the code does the same thing as your code, but it uses the reduce method to find the minimum value in each column. This eliminates the need for the inner for loop. The reduce method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single output value.

In this case, it’s used to find the minimum value in each column. The Infinity value is used as the initial value for the reduce method, so it can correctly identify the minimum value even if all values in the column are very large.